# How to resolve multi-module classpath beans in Quarkus?

Tags: cdi, quarkus

In Spring it's possible to define bean dependencies in separate modules, which are then resolved via the `classpath` at runtime. Is it possible to do something similar in Quarkus?

For example, a multi-module setup that looks like this:

```
- service
- service-test
- service-artifact
```

In Spring it's possible to define `@Configuration` in the `service` module, that resolves concrete dependencies at runtime via the `classpath` of its current context, either `service-test` or `service-artifact`, allowing injection of dummy or test dependencies when under test, and real ones in the production artifact.

For example, a class in `service` requires an instance of `SomeInterface`. The implementation of `SomeInterface` is defined in either the `-test` or `-artifact` module. The `service` module has no direct dependency on either the `-test` or `-artifact` modules.

Some code:

In the `service` module:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class OrderService(private val repository: OrderRepository) {
    fun process(order: Order) {
        repository.save(order)
    }
}

interface OrderRepository {
    fun save(order: Order)
}
```

In the `service-test` module:

```
class InMemoryOrderRepository : OrderRepository {
    val orders = mutableListOf<Order>()
    override fun save(order: Order) {
        orders.add(order)
    }
}

class OrderServiceTestConfig {
    @ApplicationScoped
    fun orderRepository(): OrderRepository {
        return InMemoryOrderRepository()
    }
}


@QuarkusTest
class OrderServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private lateinit var service: OrderService

    @Test
    fun `injected order service with resolved repository dependency`() {
        // This builds and runs OK            
        service.process(Order("some_test_order"))
    }
}
```

Where I have tried to replicate a Spring-style setup as above in Quarkus, ArC validation is failing with `UnsatisfiedResolutionException` on the build of the `service` module, even though everywhere it is actually consumed provides the correct dependencies; a test successfully resolves the dependency and passes.

How do I achieve the separation of dependency interface from the implementation, and keep ArC validation happy, with Quarkus?

(Note: this behaviour occurs with Java and Maven also.)

I have included a maven example [here](https://github.com/melissasgarden/quarkus-dependency-resolution-maven). Note that `./mvnw install` fails with the `UnsatisfiedResolutionException` but that it's possible to build and run the test successfully using `./mvnw test`.

Build files:

root project `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
        kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.3.72"
    }

allprojects {

    group = "my-group"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {

    apply {
        plugin("kotlin")
        plugin("kotlin-allopen")
    }

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    
    allOpen {
        annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
        annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
        annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
    }

    apply {
        plugin("kotlin")
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` for `service`:

```
import io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusDev

plugins {
    id("io.quarkus") version "1.9.1.Final"
}

apply {
    plugin("io.quarkus")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common:model"))
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.9.1.Final"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` for `service-test`:

```
import io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusDev

plugins {
    id("io.quarkus") version "1.9.1.Final"
}

apply {
    plugin("io.quarkus")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":service"))
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.9.1.Final"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
}
```

Comment: What are you using for creating a multi-module project? Maven or Gradle? Could you share relevant parts of your build files as an example?

Comment: I'm using Gradle (and Kotlin).. yes let me add them

Comment: This is what I found so far for Maven in the documentation for the multi-module builds: https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#multi-module-maven

In Gradle it's more difficult: https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling#multi-module-gradle. Have you tried what's written here?

Comment: Thanks yes, I am using the `META-INF/beans.xml` suggestion in each project. No joy.

Comment: OK, thanks for all the additional info. I will take a look on it.

Comment: I can create a reproducer and upload to Github if that helps.

Comment: That would definitely help to speed up things. Thanks!

Comment: @Oresztesz example available https://github.com/melissasgarden/quarkus-dependency-resolution - I cut it down for simplicity, but running the test under Intellij it builds and runs fine, however running under gradlew, you will see the ArC exception.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use instance injection (java example):

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
...
@Inject
Instance<MyBeanClass> bean;
...
bean.get(); // for a single bean
bean.stream(); // for a collection
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but it adds some type clutter - is there any way to do Spring style dependency resolution from the classpath without the additional type?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Quarkus has a bit different way of creating and injecting beans as in Spring.

It's using "[simplified bean discovery](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery)", and that means that the beans are scanned on the classpath during the build time, but only those that have annotations considered as "discovery mode", are taken into the account.

Those would be: `@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, `@ConversationScoped` and `@RequestScoped`, `@Interceptor` and `@Decorator` more [described here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#bean_defining_annotations)

In addition to that, beans must not have the visibility boundaries.

In you'd like to use beans from other modules, create a configuration class within that module. The configuration class should not have any annotation. In that config class, create beans with `@Producer` annotation and one of the above scope beans. Example in Kotlin:

```
class QuarkusConfig {
    @Producer
    @ApplicationScope
    fun myClass(myClassDependency: DependencyClass): MyClass {
        return MyClass(myClassDependency)
    }
}
```

But notice, despite that, some beans are treated by Quarkus in a special way (ex. all beans that have `@Path` annotation) and those should be annotated preferably with `@ApplicationScope`, using either constructor, or field injection. Produced by `@Producer` methods won't allow for all the magic that Quarkus is doing.

If you'd like some more quarkus dependant beans, ex. the bean that bounds a configuration (using `@ConfigMapping` annotated beans), in addition you need to have either `beans.xml` in your META-INF directory, or which seems easier to add the jandex index to your build system:

```
plugins {
  id("io.quarkus") version "2.14.1.Final"
  id("org.kordamp.gradle.jandex") version "1.0.0"
}
```

Summary: don't use configuration beans as in spring, only the constructor/field injection, and to have beans discovered from different modules, add the `jandex` index file using plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Add the descriptor file `META-INF/beans.xml` to the **resources** folder of any module where beans should be discovered.

[image]

Ref: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery